# How to remove Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project

Tags: pycharm

How can I remove the "***Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project***" from the right click context menu (shown in the picture below).

[image: 1]

Answer (score 9):

First of all, `Win + R` and type `regedit` (Registry Editor), press `Enter`.

1. To delete "Open Folder as PyCharm ..." in the menu when **right click on the folder background**:

   - Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PyCharm Community Edition`.
   - Delete the whole "PyCharm Community Edition" folder.
2. To delete "Edit with PyCharm ..." in the menu when **right click on the file icon**:

   - Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with PyCharm Community Edition`.
   - Delete the whole "Open with PyCharm Community Edition" folder.
3. To delete "Open Folder as PyCharm ..." in the menu when **right click on the folder icon**:

   - Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PyCharm Community Edition`.
   - Delete the whole "PyCharm Community Edition" folder.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me the trouble of having to uninstall and reinstall **again**. I had to change the exe location (for command and icon) after I uninstalled and reinstalled it with some issues (using Jetbrains toolbox). So these 3 locations were exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

[@LanternD's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1406801) is just correct, carefully follow the steps would solve the problem cleanly.

However, there's a tiny problem in filepath due to Markdown's escape grammar. In solution 2:

> 2. To delete "Edit with PyCharm ..." in the menu when right click on the file icon:
>
> Navigate to "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Open with PyCharm Community Edition".

The correct path should be `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with PyCharm Community Edition`. Notice this part: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`, there should be a backslash before the asterisk. Markdown grammar recognizes `\*` as trying to escape the asterisk symbol, so that backslash was omitted.

I was originally going to just edit the correct answer above, but it requires at least 6-characters' change. Also my reputation isn't enough for me to add a comment below that answer, so I chose to make a new answer instead. I am not sure if I should do it this way, please correct me if needed.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but I was unsuccessful and read many webpages to get rid    of this. After that, I found a solution which I m gonna to show you.

First of all type <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> then type `regedit` and press enter. Now, follow these steps:

1. To delete "Edit with PyCharm ..." in the menu when right click on the file icon: Navigate to    `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\Directory\shell\Open with PyCharm    Community Edition`. You have to delete this folder.
2. To delete    "Edit with PyCharm ..." in the menu when right click on the file    icon: Navigate to    `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\Directory\Background\shell\Open with    PyCharm Community Edition`. You have to delete this folder.